# Проблемы с кодировкой вывода при парсинге сайта на русском

Tags: python, веб-программирование, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Всем привет, по результатам парсинга сайта () столкнулся с проблемой что при выводе вместо привычного текста с сайта получаю в значении словаря кракозябру, аброкатабру и т.п...
Вот мой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://auto.ru/sankt-peterburg/cars/bmw/all/'
HEADERS = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.82 Safari/537.36', 'accept': '*/*'}

def get_html(url, params=None): return requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, params=params)

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('div', class_='ListingItem__main')
    # print(items)
    cars = []
    for item in items:
        cars.append({
            'title': item.find('a', class_='Link ListingItemTitle__link').get_text(strip=True),
            'link': item.find('a', class_='Link ListingItemTitle__link').get('href'),
            'prise': item.find('div', class_='ListingItemPrice__content').get_text(strip=True),
            'mileage': item.find('div', class_='ListingItem__kmAge').get_text(strip=True),
            'characteristics': item.find('div', class_='ListingItemTechSummaryDesktop__cell').get_text(strip=True),
            'year': item.find('div', class_='ListingItem__year').get_text(strip=True)

        })
    print(cars)

def parsing():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else: print('Error')

parsing()
```

В виде результата получаю:

```
[{'title': 'BMW 5 Ñ\x81ÐµÑ\x80Ð¸Ð¸ 530i xDrive VII (G30/G31)', 'link': 'https://auto.ru/cars/used/sale/bmw/5er/1115338726-1ec25076/', 'prise': '4Â\xa0550Â\xa0000Â\xa0â\x82½', 'mileage': '41Â\xa0000Â\xa0ÐºÐ¼', 'characteristics': '2.0 Ð»â\x80\x89/â\x80\x89249Â\xa0Ð».Ñ\x81.â\x80\x89/â\x80\x89Ð\x91ÐµÐ½Ð·Ð¸Ð½', 'year': '2017'}, {'title': 'BMW 5 Ñ\x81ÐµÑ\x80Ð¸Ð¸ ActiveHybrid VI (F10/F11/F07) Ð\xa0ÐµÑ\x81Ñ\x82Ð°Ð¹Ð»Ð¸Ð½Ð³', 'link': 'https://auto.ru/cars/used/sale/bmw/5er/1115345408-dbcc8f94/', 'prise': '2Â\xa0230Â\xa0000Â\xa0â\x82½', 'mileage': '165Â\xa0000Â\xa0ÐºÐ¼', 'characteristics': '3.0 Ð»â\x80\x89/â\x80\x89306Â\xa0Ð».Ñ\x81.â\x80\x89/â\x80\x89Ð\x93Ð¸Ð±Ñ\x80Ð¸Ð´', 'year': '2015'}]
```

Результат конечно урезан, но полагаю суть ясна.
К примеру в первом словаре, в значении 'mileage' должно быть '41 000 км'.
Буду очень рад вашим советам и предложениям, спасибо!

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

Передавайте в `BeautifulSoup` всё содержимое сайта `html.content`, а не только текст `html.text` без заголовков. В большинстве случаев `BS` тогда сможет разобраться по заголовкам и прочей служебной информации, какая у сайта кодировка и всё сам сделает правильно:

```py
get_content(html.content) # а не html.text
```

Проверить на конкретно вашем сайте сейчас не могу, к сожалению.

Comment: Добрый день, к сожалению данное преобразование уже предпринимал на что получал в консоли пустой список(

Comment: Странно. Может там несколько элементов `ListingItem__main`, и первый из них пустой? Попробуйте поизучать, что выдаёт `html.content`, он не может выдавать меньше информации, чем `html.text` по идее.

Comment: По какой-то причине метод .content сработал только после третьего запуска идентичного кода, но это не привело к готовому для результату тексту (например 'prise': '3\xa0610\xa0000\xa0₽', 'mileage': '142\xa0000\xa0км'), но уже этот результат можно преобразовать к идеалу функцией replace. Спасибо!

Comment: `\xa0` - это *неразрывный пробел*, да, его проще "вручную" заменить, хотя есть и другие варианты https://stackoverflow.com/a/34669482/8324991